# Vue Router - Get route params using the Vue 2 Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-router4

Im using the [Vue 2 Composition API](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api) and want to access the route parameters from the Vue Router in my `setup()` method.

As described in the [Vue Router documentation](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html#accessing-the-router-and-current-route-inside-setup):

> Because we don't have access to `this` inside of `setup`, we cannot directly access `this.$router` or `this.$route` anymore. Instead we use the `useRouter` function:
>
> ```
> import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router'
>
> export default {
>   setup() {
>     const router = useRouter()
>     const route = useRoute()
>
>     function pushWithQuery(query) {
>       router.push({
>         name: 'search',
>         query: {
>           ...route.query,
>         },
>       })
>     }
>   },
> }
> ```

Unfortunately this method is not available in the Vue Router for Vue 2. What are my options here and how can I access my route parameters using the Vue 2 Composition API?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Vue version<= 2.6 composition api you've the `root` property in the setup context that refers to the root component, try out to use it instead of `this`:

```js
export default {
  setup(props,context) {
    const router = context.root.$router;
    const route = context.root.$route;

    function pushWithQuery(query) {
      router.push({
        name: 'search',
        query: {
          ...route.query,
        },
      })
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: `context.root` came as undefined for me. I'm using Vue 2.7.14

Comment: Try to use `useRouter` and `useRoute` to get the current router and route https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html#vue-router-and-the-composition-api

Answer (score 11):

Since [version 3.6.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/CHANGELOG.md#360-2022-08-22), `useRoute` (and all other composables) can be imported from `vue-router/composables`

Answer (score 4):

The package [vue2-helpers](https://github.com/ambit-tsai/vue2-helpers#vue2-helpers) has some utils that can resolve your problem.

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue2-helpers/vue-router';

const route = useRoute();
```

Comment: Not sure how, but this works.