# How to get current route in vue2.7 composition api

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-composition-api

In Vue2, I can use `this.$route.path`

In Vue3, I can use `useRouter()`

but in Vue2.7 composition api, both of them I can't use.

Comment: Could you share some of your code as of what have you done trying for vue 2 composition ?

Comment: @A.Z Vue Router provide a useRouter() for compistion api to do this, but its only in vue router 4, its only support vue3.

Comment: @cookie_king please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/66816289/8054152  answer.

Answer (score 6):

For folks coming here from google:

Vue Router 3(current latest version is `3.6.5`) provides composables for you to use, check out release notes: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/CHANGELOG.md#360-2022-08-22

You would import it like so: `import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router/composables';`

And for the rest usage/docs you can refer to Vue Router 4 composable docs: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html

Comment: this worked for me, thnx

Comment: Had this been on the documentation, it would've saved me 10 hours of debugging with my incomplete implementation of `useRoute()` which is simply `getCurrentInstance().proxy.$route`